# How do i use the onclick function to change images javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
           function up(){

            var myShapes= new Array();

            myShapes[0]="<img src='et.png' width='150'/>"
            myShapes[1]="<img src='bulb.png' width='150'/>"
            myShapes[2]="<img src='raind.png' width='150'/>"


            var woe=Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

            document.write(myShapes[woe])

             }
             up()
```

im a novice at best i would like to use the images as buttons each time there clicked the pics turn into a different pic randomly. if i refresh the page a different image appears every time so i know im on the right track i just need help making that work when the image is pressed not just when the page is refreshed. Thank You!

Comment: Where is the HTML? You need to use this: <img src="" OnClick="up()" id="clickImages" />

Comment: AT-2016 thank you for the reply i did not see you sent one as you can tell im new to programming and stack overflow, would you use that method in a body tag or some other place?

Comment: I've already given you an example. Without using HTML or HTML tag, it is not possible to make the images clicked to change.

Answer (score 0):

**1:** There's no need to allocate and populate the images array `myShapes` in every evaluation of the function, since it's constant for all evaluations. In other words, we can define it once as a global variable during page load, and access it as an enclosing variable from inside the [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

**2:** It might be better to define only the URLs of the images in `myShapes`, rather than the full HTML of the `<img>` tag. We can then set the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag from the selected array element, rather than writing dynamic HTML. This means we'll need to call the function after the page has finished loading using an `onload` handler; this is necessary to ensure the `<img>` element has been processed by the time the JavaScript function runs. This is usually how dynamic content is generated, so it's preferable, rather than making `document.write()` calls during page load.

**3:** To make the picture change on a click of the picture, we need to add an `onclick` handler to the image element which will call the function.

```js
var myShapes = [
    'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e8f9bc86c31c62823171c2c83c249526?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1',
    'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4fa45261dec56004145c653832504920?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1',
    'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fa7fe8a1a8d8f84ef89a80c783bcd9e7?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1',
];

function setRandomImage() {
    var imgElem = document.getElementById('img1');
    imgElem.setAttribute('src',myShapes[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]);
} // end setRandomImage()
```

```html
<body onload="setRandomImage();">
  <img id="img1" width="150" onclick="setRandomImage();"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank You A Million bgoldst!!! i really, really appreciate that ive been trying to get this going for a while!

Comment: You still have the full HTML in `myShapes`, i.e. the `<img>` tags. The `myShapes` array should store only the URLs of the images, not any HTML. In other words, change the assignment to `var myShapes = ['et.png','bulb.png','raind.png'];`.

Comment: F^*king YEESSSSSS, yes, yes, now i tried it out and got it...wow finally! Thats better than make up... make up magic and a new pair of shoes! How  long did it take for you to learn this if you dont mind me asking??? - bgoldst

Comment: :) Glad to help. With respect to your question, are you asking how long it took me to learn web programming in general? Or something more specific? I have years of experience dabbling in web programming...

Comment: Yes sir thats what i was asking, but my main and hopefully My last question for a bit is; i had 3 sets of 2 images like team 1 (1&2) team2 (3&4) team 3 (5&6) team1- image 1 turns into image 2 when clicked everytime image 3 into 4 when pressed everytime 5into6 when pressed everytime. but the teams/sets switch and show randomly. is it possible to do that? the method i was using b4 almost worked.                                 document.getElementById("b1").onclick=function() {
document.getElementById("ci").style.display="block"
document.getElementById("b1").style.display="none"
go()
}

Comment: i hope its appropriate to ask hear if not i will erase it but here was the old method   document.getElementById("b1").onclick=function() {
document.getElementById("ci").style.display="block"
document.getElementById("b1").style.display="none"
go()

}


document.getElementById("b2").onclick=function() {
document.getElementById("oc").style.display="block"
document.getElementById("b2").style.display="none"
go()

}


document.getElementById("b3").onclick=function() {
document.getElementById("c3").style.display="block"
document.getElementById("b3").style.display="none"
go()

}

Comment: Hi @altitudeup. The answer to this new question depends on other details, like the HTML, and perhaps what `go()` does. I suggest asking a completely new question on Stack Overflow and posting all the relevant code. :)